# Unable to install Arch Linux on SD card via Virtual Box

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, virtualbox

My aim is to create a bootable SD card with Arch Linux, for my Raspberry Pi.

I have been trying to follow [this guide](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi) without success.

So far I have:

- A working Arch Linux virtual box, as my host is OSX
- Formatted the SDcard to FAT before the process
- Mounted my SDcard to and it is visible by the VM as storage

I go to start following the guide and things start going wrong.

Unsure on how to 'get' at the device that is available I ran `/dev/disk/by-label` and saw my device `@RECOVERY` which is the correct label. Great.

I then executed step 2 of the guide, as my SDcard is formatted. `mkfs.vfat /dev/disk/RECOVERY`.. the only thing that happened is that my SDcard is no longer visible in `/dev/disk/by-label` ! My assumption is that I have in some way mounted the device but I am now out of my depth, even after googling for mounted devices/partitions I remain lost.

What is my equivalent of `/dev/sdX1` and how do I complete step 3 and 4 of the guide?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can check in /dev to see the names of your storage devices. Usually they will be something like mmcblkNpn, where N is the storage device number and n is the partition number.

For you it is most likely mmcblk0p1 for the boot and mmcblk0p2 for root, you can try to mount them those then check to see if they are correct.